Erasing Quantum Wire and Adding Dotted Arrows in Quantikz
I am trying to create a quantum circuit. See the attached image. I'd like to erase the quantum wire in the second row so I can put three vertical dotted arrows in the first column of the circuit to indicate that potentially the circuit depends on an arbitrary number $n$ of qubits chosen.
I cannot find a solution to this problem with the quantikz package. Suggestions?

Code:
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}
\usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{quantikz}[wire types={q,q,q},classical gap=0.07cm]
            \gategroup[wires=3,steps=6,style={rounded corners,draw=none,fill=blue!20}, background]{$U$}
            \lstick{$\ket{0} \; \; $} & \gate{H} & &  & \meter{} & \\
            \lstick{$\ket{0} \; \; $} & &  &  &  & \\
            \lstick{$\ket{0} \; \; $} & \gate{X} &  &  &  &  
        \end{quantikz}
       % \caption{Caption}
        %\label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}

